# HP-ux operating system in vi editor

Tags: hp-ux

I am using hp-ux os . When i am giving the vi editor i am getting Terminal too wide error.

I tried "stty columns 120" & "stty columns 160" also. But doesn't helped me.

Can anyone let me know how to fix this problem.

Br,
Moorthy

Comment: VI has a column limit of 160 columns. Have you tried VIM? https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/15844

Answer (score 0):

Old systems have much harsher restrictions than you are apparently used to. For reference, the HP-UX 11.23 system I have access to happily opened terminals up to 212 chars wide. So I suspect you have an even older HP-UX version, and you are out of luck.

I suggest you either edit somewhere else, or get used to 80 and 132 character wide terminals (which is what physical terminals supported, back in the days.)